# Laravel Json Data Store multiple array in mysql database

Tags: php, sql, arrays, json, laravel

Hello All of Seniors and Juniors,
I am working on courier company and recently i try to add small features in my current application. I have an database table name is `driver` There i have added some column bellow the list:

`Name` => `Address` => `Price`

So what i want In `price` Column I have json data, bellow example:

```
[
{
"type":"truck",
"price_km":50,
"size":30,
"quantity":10,
"weight":25
},
{
"type":"vehA",
"price_km":40,
"size":20,
"quantity":10,
"weight":25
}
]
```

This is static data that i inserted by directly database, I want it dynamically. So, How to design blade file for that and how to store and update it. Bellow I am trying this:

```
<input type="text" name="rate_chilometrico_type[]" />
<input type="text" name="rate_chilometrico_type[]" />
<input type="text" name="rate_chilometrico_type[]" />
<input type="text" name="rate_chilometrico_type[]" />
```

And I got response like this:

```
  "rate_chilometrico_type": [
    "truck",
    "50",
    "30",
    "10",
    "25",
    "vehA",
    "40",
    "20",
    "10",
    "25",
    "truck",
    "34",
    "54",
    "45",
    "45"
  ]
```

But I want:

```
[
{
"type":"truck",
"price_km":50,
"size":30,
"quantity":10,
"weight":25
},
{
"type":"vehA",
"price_km":40,
"size":20,
"quantity":10,
"weight":25
}
]
```

Comment: please provide the controller code what you did so far and where is the problem

Comment: I need out put correct first, after i will work on controller. Currently form didnt give me correct result. read again my question of last.

Comment: okay, I got it you want to save the whole JSON in that price column?

Comment: yes off-course man

Comment: okay then first convert your request rate_chilometrico_type into array like,
json_encode($request->rate_chilometrico_type and then see the resuly

Comment: great then. goog luck